# bind Shift-; to execute-extended-command

Tags: key-bindings

What is the proper way to bind `S-;` to `execute-extended-command`?

I tried this `(bind-key* "S-;" 'execute-extended-command)` but doesn't work. `bind-key` is a function from `use-package`.

### Update

I use `evil` mode.

Comment: Are you able to type `Shift+:`? Most keyboards require pressing shift just to enter a `:`.

Comment: @npostavs thanx for pointing out. I have updated the question

Comment: Ah, I don't think you can type `S-;` from Emacs' point of either, you probably just want to bind `:`.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out how to define a key binding that emacs can understand, simply do `C-h c` or `C-h k` following by pressing the keys you intend to bind.

In this case, doing `C-h c` followed by `Shift+;` gives `:`. So you need to bind the command to `:`.

So taking your example, it should be,

```el
(bind-key* ":" #'execute-extended-command)
```